# Translating from a String to a Timestamp and back

Tags: java, date, timestamp, date-formatting, date-comparison

I work with the date in my API on Java. I want to get today's date and time, write it to a class and then to a csv file (I use a csv file as a data store). Then, to implement the function of getting a report on records for today, to get it and to compare it with today's date (exactly the date, without time). What is the best way to do this? Right now I'm storing this in Timestamp, but it doesn't seem to be correct and should I use String? Then I need two parsers? To translate from a string to a date and time and from that to just a DATE? Which library is better to use for this?

I wrote a translation from a string to a timestamp, is this correct?

```
default Timestamp StringToTimestamp(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
    Date parsedDate = null;
    try {
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Error in date parsing");
    }
    return new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
}
```

UPD
I changed my code for the java.time library, but it seems I did something wrong

```
 default LocalDate StringToTimestamp(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyy-mm-dd');
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
        return date;
    }
```

UPD I edited the code according to the answer @OleV.V. It works really cool

Comment: Good you asked. I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Can you edit this question to include details about the larger problem you're trying to solve? It isn't clear to me how the CSV file is involved here. Right now, it reads as if you are getting the current date, writing that to a file, reading it back immediately, and then trying to compare values. Try to omit the file entirely in that case. If I've misunderstood, please ***edit** this question* to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. I suggest writing the current date and time with offset from UTC to the CSV file.

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String stringForCsvFile = dateTime.toString();
    System.out.println(stringForCsvFile);
```

Output when running in my time zone just now:

> 2020-12-26T11:02:07.368973+01:00

The string is in ISO 8601 format, which should be the best to avoid surprises for anyone reading it. The classes of java.time generally print ISO 8601 format from their `toString` methods.

Often you will value consistency higher than knowing which UTC offset was used when writing the file. If so, write the time in UTC to the file:

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    String stringForCsvFile = now.toString();
```

> 2020-12-26T10:02:07.373439Z

No matter which way you used above, after reading the timestamp from the file, convert like this:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    String stringFromCsvFile = "2020-12-26T11:02:07.368973+01:00";
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(stringFromCsvFile)
            .atZoneSameInstant(zone);
    LocalDate dateFromCsv = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    
    System.out.println("Same day? " + dateFromCsv.isEqual(today));
```

> Same day? true

I have made sure that both dates I compare are in the time zone of the JVM where the program is running. Please consider whether there’s a specific time zone you want, and if so, set `zone` to something like `ZoneId.of("Asia/Baku")`. It matters: it is never the same date in all time zones.

If you want to know whether the date is earlier or later, use the `isBefore` or `isAfter` method of `LocalDate`.

### Was your code correct?

IMHO the worst problem with your code is using the old and poorly designed date-time classes: `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class. `Date` had severe design flaws in Java 1.0, therefore most constructors and methods were deprecated already in Java 1.1. `Timestamp` was never meant for other purposes than transferring high-precision timestamps to and from SQL databases (which we also don’t use it for anymore). And it’s a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date` class. I furthermore see nothing that you will want to use the high precision of `Timestamp` for, so using it here seems pointless.

There is a bug in your code: You are using upper case `YYYY` in your format pattern. This is for week year and only useful with a week number. I tried giving `24-06-2021` to your method. It returned `2021-01-04 00:00:00.0`. It’s 5 months 20 days off because of the mentioned error. Apparently `SimpleDateFormat` defaulted to the start of week 1 in the week year and ignored the month and day of month.

As an aside, had you tried parsing with the same format pattern string with java.time, it would at least have told you that this was wrong.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Related question: java parsing string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546742/java-parsing-string-to-date)